# javaee statefull bean not working

Tags: session, java-ee-7, wildfly-8, stateful-session-bean

I've defined an `@Stateful @StatefulTimeout(value = 2, unit = TimeUnit.HOURS)` rest bean so that it can hold a `private MyContext userContext;` (basically a `List<String>` holding all previous values passed to the rest bean).

I've launched my webapp in a wildfly 8.1 container on openshift.

Unfortunatly my bean is not working properly.

It seems that the bean is re-created on each call as if the container was unable to relates two calls to the same session. This seems to be confirmed by the fact that there is no cookie nor session id param on the client side.

What could be missing in my app / conf ? Why isn't wildfly automatically creating a user session ?

---

Edit : sample code : https://github.com/GrmpCerber/testStatefulRest

Comment: PS. if you don't have a clue because wildfly should deal with it automatically just "+1" this comment or leave your own so that I this is not a normal behavior from wildfly

Comment: A code sample could help.  Have you tested that bean/sample on other servers such as Glassfish?

Comment: @AlexanderLanger I've uploaded a sample : https://github.com/GrmpCerber/testStatefulRest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code sample, it seems you are missing a `@SessionScoped` annotation, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14911005/1757320).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, If you have 5 more minutes ;) I've updated my sample and posted a new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591140/containerresponsefilter-not-working

Comment: Sorry, no idea with the other one (never used it)

Comment: Thanks anyway ! it was nice from you to give a look at it