# ContainerResponseFilter not working

Tags: resteasy, wildfly-8

In wildfly 8.1 with REST services, I wanted to implement CORS ContainerRequestFilter and ContainerResponseFilter.

My request filter is working properly but `ContainerResponseFilter` never gets loaded nor called

```java
package org.test.rest;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider 
@PreMatching // <-- EDIT : This was my mistake ! DO NOT ADD THIS
public class CorsResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    public CorsResponseFilter() {
        System.out.println("CorsResponseFilter.init");
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext req,
            ContainerResponseContext resp) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("CorsResponseFilter.filter");
        resp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        resp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        resp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Content-Type, Accept");
    }

}
```

This seems to me as a Wildfly / resteasy bug. Do you have another idea / am I missing something ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing `ContainerRequestFilter` and `ContainerResponseFilter` in your question. As you want to send additional Headers to the client the `ContainerResponseFilter` is the right one.

The [@PreMatching](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/PreMatching.html) annotation can be applied to a `ContainerRequestFilter` "to indicate that such filter should be applied globally on all resources in the application before the actual resource matching occurs".

Adding it to a `ContainerResponseFilter` does not make sense. Just remove the annotation and your filter should work.