# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" error during exceptions on JAX-RS requests

Tags: exception, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I am able to communicate with my back end with my AngularJS application via restful calls. The JAX-RS calls work e.g. Logging in or getting data from the backend. This is because I do have a `CORSResponseFilter` in the application:

```
@Provider    
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter { 
    @Override
    public void filter( ContainerRequestContext requestCtx, ContainerResponseContext responseCtx ) throws IOException {
        responseCtx.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" );
        responseCtx.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" );
        responseCtx.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT" );
        responseCtx.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    }
}
```

The problem I have is when something goes wrong with the JAX-RS call. If there is an internal server error or a `BadRequest` exception is thrown the front end responds with:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

In the GlassFish logs however I get:

> Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[ServletAdaptor]: Servlet.service() for servlet ServletAdaptor threw exception
>       org.project.dashboard.exceptions.BadRequestException: (400) : Invalid date format should be yyyy-MM-dd

As you can see with the GlassFish log, the exception is being mapped to the correct error and response code but that doesn't permeate through to the front end. I only ever get the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" error. I do not receive this error when the response code is 200.

---

**UPDATE**

The `ResponseFilter` is used when there are no exceptions thrown but when there is then the `ResponseFilter` isn't touched.

Here is the code for my exception mapper which maybe causing the issue:

```
@Provider
public class DashboardExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<DashboardException> {

@Override
public Response toResponse(DashboardException e) {
    ErrorMessage error = new ErrorMessage();
    error.setStatus(e.getHttpStatusCode());
    error.setCode(e.getClass().getSimpleName());
    error.setMessage(e.getShortMessage());

    return Response.status(e.getHttpStatusCode()).entity(error)
            .build();
}
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Code for the Exception that is thrown:

```
public class BadRequestException extends DashboardException{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public BadRequestException(String message) {
    super(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, message);
}

}
```

---

**UPDATE 3**

Requested full stack trace of one of the exceptions:

```
        Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[ServletAdaptor]: Servlet.service() for servlet ServletAdaptor threw exception
    org..dashboard.exceptions.AuthenticationException: (403) : An invalid sessionID has been provided
        at org..dashboard.exposed.DashboardREST.getRoutes(DashboardREST.java:330)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor191.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor170.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor172.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy414.getRoutes(Unknown Source)
        at org.dashboard.exposed.__EJB31_Generated__DashboardREST__Intf____Bean__.getRoutes(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor191.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I just want to comment that using CORS headers in this kind of "allow all" fashion is quite dangerous. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/25638018/499922

Comment: Yes I have looked through the dependancy tree and I get javax.rs from javaee-api-7.0 but not what jersey version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter isn't working because your custom `ExceptionMapper` not working. Annotating it with `@Provider` annotation is not enough you should also include package in which it resides into provider packages configuration or register this custom exception mapper manually.

For example:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>org.dashboard.exposed,org.dashboard.exceptions</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Note that exact value of `<init-param>` name depends on version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

In general `ContainerResponseFilter` will always executed, see [Server filters](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html):

> The filter will be executed for every response which is in most cases after the resource method is executed. Response filters are executed even if the resource method is not run, for example when the resource method is not found and 404 "Not found" response code is returned by the Jersey runtime. In this case the filter will be executed and will process the 404 response.

See also: [Filter and interceptor execution order](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9915) and [JAX_RS_SPEC-230](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_RS_SPEC-230).

But the providers have to be `public`, see [JERSEY-2094](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2094), [JERSEY-2096](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2096) and [JERSEY-2097](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2097).

In some cases `@PreMatching` disables `ContainerResponseFilter`, see [ContainerResponseFilter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25638018/5277820).

Also, you have to know, that you can't add headers, if the reponse is already [committed](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#isCommitted--).